# If a blogger writes a whole article about my website, how important are anchor texts?

Tags: seo, keywords, blog, anchor, post

If there is a full article about my web-service, with my brand name in the title, and many relevant keywords that I would like Google to consider in my rankings, and links to my web-site with simple anchor text such as `<brand name>` and `<page title>`.

Does it make a big difference if I get links to the actual keywords I'm after, or is it enough that these keywords are part of the written text?

Comment: If a blogger writes an article about your website then they should link to it how it makes sense to their audience. Anchor text is not as powerful as it used to be and if you over do it your feel the wrath of the Penguins foot.

Comment: @bybe thanks, that's helpful. Not really thinking about over doing it, was just considering requesting an addition of one link, but if you're saying it's not that important, i'll let things be.

Answer (score 1):

In short, make sure that anchor texts are diversed. Eg: `<brand name>`, `<page title>`, www.`<site_url>`.com, `<click here>` and more.

In this post Penguin, Panda & Hummingbird era, Google see signals from different ways. If they find they we try to manipulate the game by using some sort of same anchor texts, we'll get banned by them.